# Word Interop .InsertFile result in lost styles

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have some C# code that merges one file into another.  It it is a pretty straight forward process:

```
//open the files
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document file1 = winWord.Documents.Open(ref
    file1address, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document insertfile = 
     winWord.Documents.Open(ref insertfileaddress, ReadOnly: true, 
     Visible: false);

//activate file1
file1.Activate();

// insert a page break
 file1.Words.Last.
    InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
    WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);

//move to end and insert insertfile 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selection = winWord.Selection;
selection = winWord.Selection;

selection.
    EndOf(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdStory, 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);

selection.InsertFile(insertfileaddress.ToString(), missing, 
     missing, missing, missing);

// save under a new name
file1.SaveAs2(NewFileName);
```

In my project I use this code twice.  The first time I generate a file that is about 300 pages long,  That time it works great.

The second time is much bigger - the resulting file is over 15,000 pages long - and in that case the problem occurs.  The paragraph styling is all lost - all paragraphs come through as Normal.  (What I care about is header paragraphs maintaining their "Header 1" or "Header 2" or "Header 3" designations.

In both cases file1 is the same, and the insertfile is generated elsewhere using word interop - and the code that generates those file is the same as the code in both the smaller and larger versions.  The file characteristics and the characteristics of the content is all the same - but I lose the "Header" styles in the bigger version.

The only solution i can think of is to go through the new file and apply styles again.

If anyone out there has an idea of why this is happening, and how to fix it, please help.

Comment: What happens if you try this as a user? Does the problem still occur? If yes, then you need to research the problem first from that angle - how to get it to work in the UI. As to your code: why are you opening two files? I do not recommend opening a file you want to insert...

Comment: yes, the problem still occurs with the bigger files (but with the smaller files it works fine - the styles persist after the insertfile().  
thanks for the recommendation about the second file.
Since the other day I also tried doing a wildcard find/replace - which works using word on my desktop.  But doing it with find object in interop fails (only with the large files) - I get an exception message that the service is unavailable.
My latest try is looping through the paragraphs and applying styles as warranted by text content - works but very slow.  Still looking for a better way.

Comment: But you can open this very large file in Word and the styles are retained? A possible faster way would be to break this up into smaller documents before importing. Another possible approach that's probably a LOT faster would be to leverage the WordOpenXML file format, using the Open XML SDK to do this work instead of the "interop".

Comment: Cindy M - thanks. I experimented with file sizes a little but gave up after still getting the problem at 5,000 pages.
Your recommendation to use the WordOpenXML SDK was awesome. The merge now has 2 steps - I merge the files using Word OpenXML, and then I use word interop to update the table of contents (which is part of why i need the heading styles). Looping through all paragraphs works - but takes over 6 hours to complete, and I need to keep doc active or I get "object deleted" crash (your posts elsewhere helped on that exception). New process takes about 40 minutes. TOC takes most time

Comment: Glad you got it working satisfactorily! Yes, the TOC would take a long time for such a large document. Actually, you're lucky you're doing this now and not 10, 15 years ago: back then Word had a maximum file size that was well under what you're attempting!

Answer (score 2):

As you'll see in the comments above I tried several things.  A working solution was to loop through all paragraphs and replace styles based on a wildcard match. Doing that required making sure the document remained active (I did that by adding an activate line in the loop).  But it took over 6 hours to complete - which was not reasonable.

Based on the comment from C. Meister above I tried OpenXML, which was great.  The only problem was that OpenXML does not run word functions like 'update Table of Contents.'  So I ended up with 2 methods.  One to append one file to another and save the resulting file (with styles intact!) - using OpenXML.  And the second opens the document in word interop, updates the Table of Contents and sets some settings the way I want them, and saves the file.

Here is my code:

```
{
string targetFile = "c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\targetFile.docx";
string appendThisFile = "c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\appendThisFile.docx";
string newFile = "c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\newFile.docx";

object newFileObj = newfile;  // will need this later to save file

AppendFileToEnd(targetFile, appendThisFile, newFile);

UpdateTOCplusSettings(newFile, ref winWord);
}

// This method appends  puts a page break at the end of "targetFile" and 
then appends "appendThisFile."
// This method requires adding the WordOpenXML SDK - add using nuget
internal void AppendFileToEnd(string targetFile, string appendThisFile, 
string newFile)
    {
        File.Delete(newFile);
        File.Copy(targetFile, newFile);

        using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFile, true))
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";

            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph para = new 
              DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(new 
              DocumentFormat
                .OpenXml.Wordprocessing
                .Run((new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { 
                  Type = BreakValues.Page })));

            mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(para, 
               mainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);

            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk =
                mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, 
                altChunkId);

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(appendThisFile, 
                 FileMode.Open))
                 chunk.FeedData(fileStream);

            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
            mainPart.Document
                .Body
                .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
                .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
                   .Paragraph>().Last());
           mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }

 // This method opens a document and updates the first Table of Contents.
 // Note that my project already has a Word Interop object, so I pass it in 
       // and use it.  If you don't have an Word object then you need to 
       // create one before opening the doc file)
 // I also turn off grammar and spelling error - which is a choice of mine      
 internal void UpdateTOCplusSettings(string filename, ref 
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword)
 {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = 
            winword.Documents.Open(filename);
        wordDocument.ShowGrammaticalErrors = false;
        wordDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = false;
        wordDocument.TablesOfContents[1].Update();
        wordDocument.Save();
  }
```

Instead of 6 hours (plus) this process takes a little over 6 minutes.  The appending method takes less than a second, and the TOC update takes 6 minutes.  The save takes about a second.